# Multiple root tags error (in syles.xml file)

Tags: java, android-studio

I get the error "Multiple root tags" with red markings under the "<" Before the two "style" (Se code bellow), and and i can't seem to fix it. This error occurs in the "styles.xml" file in the values folder. Does anyone that's better at Android studios then me have an idea how to fix this? /André

```
...

</resources>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your opening tag: `<resources>` and closing tag: `</resources>` need to be the first and last lines of your styles.xml file. In the code you showed your two declared styles need to be above the closing `</resources>` tag.

It should look like this:

```xml
<resources>

<!--Code you have-->

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```